# Making Apigility usable for logged in users only, with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

How can I use the authentication of the  [Apigility](https://apigility.org/) API to make it secure for logged in users only?

Right now all I do when user logs in, is create session (common).

I need to do more, I need to somehow authorize him to the API as well and block everyone else (none logged)

I'm kinda new to ZF2 and Apigility so please do the dummy talk.

I did read about [Apigility Auth2](https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-oauth2) and rather not use this.

I need something simpler, for example when you log in to facebook you can then "allow" other apps to use your facebook account without having to relog, same should be for the api.

Comment: It's for the admin interface of apigilty?

Comment: No

I am using `angularjs` as client side and I want to be able to send api calls to the API but only after login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [**ZF-Campus - ZF MVC Auth**](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-mvc-auth#zf-mvc-auth) for that. It is a module for `Apigility` which does exactly that. It is an Acl with limited functionality, it only checks if users are authenticated and if they are allowed to do a certain request (method on controller). You can also configure permissions for unauthenticated users (Guests).

Check the repository [**here**](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-mvc-auth).

Answer (score 0):

You need the OAuth Module,

https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-oauth2#browser-based-applications

The workflow is like the facebook,

You have to send user to a url of OAuth Module, user will allow or deny the request of access data and the app will redirect to your page with a token to access the API.

If the front-end and api is from the same developer, you can use a most simple way with username and password.

https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-oauth2#username-and-password-access

In this workflow, the user will pass the username and password in your front application.

Your frontend will send a request to API with this data and will receive a access token.

This approach is recommend when the API and Front is of the same developer or a trusted developer.

Comment: I tried it, some limitations of OAuth made me have to decline it.

Comment: what limitations make you decline it?

Comment: And the limitation is?

Comment: That I do not want authentication logic, but rather a login logic.

Comment: After your client side application receive a access token, you are logged, if I understand that you say. the access token is like a session, and you can configure a expire time to this.

Comment: Thats not such a bad idea.